# Why is this IC ok for high voltage?

Tags: integrated-circuit, high-voltage, nixie

I've used some SN74141 BCD-TO-DEC/DRIVER I had laying around to drive some nixie tubes recently, and I have also seen someone on the internet use HV5622 High Voltage Shift Register. I looked at both devices datasheet, but I can't find  any information about why the work with high voltage, how much voltage can they take or why they act as a GND connection (as in the example below from http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Control-a-Nixie-Tube-with-an-Arduino/).

[image: Circuit Example]

PS. By acting as GND I mean that the tube is discharging through it, has this something to do with High Voltage capabilities?

Comment: Parameter "High-voltage Output Voltage"?

Comment: Page 4? http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005854A.pdf

Comment: Yes, but High Voltage could mean any High Voltage, how do I know what exact maximum voltage is?

Comment: @WesleyLee So... as I understand, the High Voltage has to do with the IC outputs, being open drain?

Comment: Not directly, since many open-drain devices can't tolerate 200V+.

Comment: `Does the datasheet provide any information about the maximum voltage? Because for both the ICs I really couldn't find it` Sorry, I just found the max Vout on the link you sent

Comment: Did you look at page 4 of the document I linked?

Comment: Yes thank you very much, if you put the answer down here, I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that 200VDC can be quite dangerous and if you are not familiar with electronics perhaps you should start with other projects. Be careful and stay safe.

From HV5622 [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005854A.pdf) page 4:

[image]

p.s.: was a bit conflicted about answering this since its just a URL, but I guess its better than leaving it open and the question popping back up..

Comment: Ok thank you very much, don't worry I have already worked with high voltage electronics in other sectors ;)

Comment: Oh, ok! Good luck and have fun. (The note is also useful for future readers)

Answer (score 1):

> SN74141 BCD-TO-DEC/DRIVER [...] HV5622 High Voltage Shift Register
>
> I looked at both devices datasheet, but I can't find any information about why the work with high voltage

They have output drivers which are specifically designed to cope with high output voltage (e.g. high V<sub>CEO</sub> for BJT and high V<sub>DS</sub> for MOSFET).

> how much voltage can they take

This is given in the datasheets. Recommended maximums:

- SN74141: 60V
- HV5622: 220V

> why they act as a GND connection

This is the nature of open-collector (74141) / open-drain (HV5622) output drivers.